# Is there any software or hack to disable touchpad while mouse is plugged in?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Is there any software or a hack that will disable the touchpad while a mouse is plugged in, and re-enable it once the mouse is unplugged?

Extra information that might help:

- Computer is a Gateway NX680XL
- I'm using a Synaptics TouchPad
- Drivers are updated to 14.0.3
- No such options can be found within Windows Mouse Properties
- No such options can be found within Properties for Synaptics TouchPad

Comment: This could depend on both your hardware and your operating system, so state the exact model of your touchpad (if you don't know, which is likely, give the exact model of your laptop) and your operating system.

Comment: The model is a Gateway NX860XL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is, if your laptop along with the software doesn't support this feature then it isn't possible for the touchpad to automatically enable or disable when a external mouse is plugged in?

That is what I am reading in forums like this [one](http://www.n10user.com/viewtopic.php?id=932).

Comment: Even checked bios.

Answer (score 5):

My Synaptics touchpad, on my Asus notebook, has a setting to turn itself off if an external mouse is plugged in. Check your manufacturer's website for updated touchpad drivers and you might find the solution you're looking for.

EDIT:

[This link](http://support.gateway.com/support/drivers/getFile.asp?id=21246&dscr=Windows%20Vista%20(32-bit%20or%2064-bit)%20Synaptics%20Touchpad%20DriverVersion:%209.1.3.0&uid=288576640) came up. Give it a shot.

Comment: Yes, I know some laptop will come with software or drivers that do this. However, this isn't is the case with my Gateway. Thanks for the quick answer Randolph.

Comment: Which model do you have? Acer makes Gateways so maybe there *is* something you can use?

Comment: The model is a Gateway NX860XL. It's about 3 years old. Currently it's my primary laptop but will be replaced very soon. Just waiting on my new [ASUS G73JW-A1](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0041RRS0I/ref=oss_product). I heard that the ASUS laptops do come with this feature. But I am trying to get it for the Gateway too.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a URL to a driver download for Windows 7.

Comment: Install the synaptics driver and you'll be able to do that. It sounds like for some reason the driver wasn't installed yet, but if you download that, it should work.

Comment: I believe I have tried this already in the past. But I will try it again. Might be a day before I can. In Afghanistan right now and the internet here for the past day has been going in and out. Just give me some time and I will post my results.

Comment: I updated the drivers of Synaptic touchpad to the latest (v14.0.3) that I found at Synaptic's official site. That's because the drivers you link wouldn't run for some reason (maybe bc I upgraded to Win7 64bit) and the drivers were out-of-date (v9.1.0). The results were the same. No option within the mouse properties or properties for the Synaptic Touchpad. Thank you though.